# @Font-face not showing capital "A" in some browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, frontend

Strange problem here. I'm using `@font-face` for a site and am having some issues. I initially wasn't getting capital "A"s to show up in Chrome on Mac. After setting a font-weight explicitly, anything above `300`, it was fine.

Now, however, I'm seeing that it occurs in Firefox and on my clients machine in various browsers.

Here's my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    src: url('../fonts/tricky.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/tricky.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/tricky.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/tricky.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/tricky.svg#ModernPictogramsNormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can see it live here: http://infirmaryhealth.mdidev.com/

Thanks for any assistance-

Comment: i see your searchbar is also not working when i browse through your site.

Comment: thanks, but it's still just a placeholder image. lots of wrinkles still in place like that. this issue in particular is actually an issue that i've attempted to fix w/o any success tho.

Comment: The page mentioned does not declare or use the Avenir font.

Comment: whoops. thanks for that, copied wrong page in. edited post to reflect change.

Comment: there are a bunch of css files, where do we find the code for @font-face you talked about? Also which A for instance has trouble in firefox?

Comment: all capital "A"s in headers like on home page (e.g. 'FEATURED VIDEO'). it's in the `vars.css` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue figured out.

I was using Zurb's Foundation framework. They have this applied to `h1` to `h6`:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Commented it out and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font-weight to normal (that's the same as setting it to 400). It's what the fontsquirrel @font-face generator does after converting fonts and it works for me all the time.